# Is it a verse or stanza?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, poetry

Is "verse" or "stanza" the proper word to refer to some "paragraph" in a poem? For example, in Edgar Allan Poe's *The Raven*

> *Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,
>
>   Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore,
>
>   While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,
>
>   As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.
>
>   "'Tis some visitor," I muttered, "tapping at my chamber door-
>
>   Only this, and nothing more."*

Do we call this the first **verse** or the first **stanza** of this poem? I know there was a previous question on this site asking about the difference between the two words but I cannot find any example on that page and I am still confused. Could anyone clarify things to me in this very example? Best regards

Comment: Note that in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verse), definition 3 of *verse* is *stanza*.

Comment: So here we can use both? @PeterShor

Comment: *Stanza* refers unambiguously to a verse "paragraph" whereas *verse* has a wider ranger of meanings.  If you asked someone to recite the first verse of a poem, they might give you only the first line or the first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stanza is a paragraph like form of poetry, when compared to prose writing.
A verse is simply a sentence.